# SQL - (Foreign key?) constraint to table names?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm curious if something like this is possible, if at all reasonable.
I have a column in a table, that's called `ref_table` and it points to a table that the current entry relates to. Let's say, in table `table_people`, `Person ID` 1 is a client and `Person ID` 3 is an employee, so respectively their `ref_tables` will show "table_clients" and "table_emplyees". I shouldn't have a problem keeping the values valid through PHP, but what would some ways of achieving it through SQL be?

I tried testing it with a foreign key constraint to INFROMATION_SCHEMA:

```
FOREIGN KEY `people_constraint_tables` (`ref_table`)
      REFERENCES `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`(`COLUMN_NAME`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

No point refining it since it didn't work. It seems like there's one way to make it work but it is a dirty cheat apparently.

Would you do it with triggers? Would you do it at all? Someone with experience with MySQL tell me if that'sreasonable at all, I'd like to know. Thank you.

Comment: It's a waste of time and energy. Nobody's forcing you to use a RDBMS, but if you do, do it properly.

Comment: Having one field reference multiple tables is generally a bad idea. The first question that springs to mind is why aren't `table_clients` and `table_employees` just referencing `table_people`, and maybe table_people just having a person_type field that doesn't reference anything? Even if you decide to go that route, what usability do you expect it to get you?

Comment: I was generally following this guide: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server - although I had to adapt since not all of it works. In short, it helps ensure that you don't have a person that's both a client and an employee (in my case). I was curious because more than "how" to achieve something, it helps to know the "why" and the "whether to".

Comment: I think the approach from your link should work (`foreign key (PersonID, PersonTypeID) references People(PersonID, PersonTypeID)`).

Comment: Yeah of course. I changed PersonTypeID to strings of PersonType tables to make it easier to read, amd I was wondering if it was possible to further constraint the PersonType to only be able to insert existing table names. Not necessary per se, but interesting. I mean, it works as it is already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have the facility to do this easily.  Other databases do, through generated columns or table inheritance.

Would I do this with triggers?  Well, yes and no.  If I had to do this with one table and I had to use MySQL and I wanted to introduce relational integrity, then triggers are the way to go.  There is little other choice.

But really, I would simply have a different table for each reference type.  There is a little bit of overhead in this (in terms of partially filled tables).  And for some applications, a single reference table is quite convenient (internationalization comes to mind).  But in general, I would stick with the standard method of a separate table for each entity with properly declared foreign key relationships.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me directions to research. You mentioned other databases that can do this, could you point to some?